# apache stops working after httpd.conf php configuring

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I want to install dompdf, and so I need PHP, and consequently Apache (for instance) installed. I've managed to install Apache 2.0.64 on my Windows 7 64 bit. It was apparently working fine, until I've installed PHP 5.4.9 and configured httpd.conf, so Apache could "see" the PHP installation. I've been using this link for guidance on that -> http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-PHP-windows-7.php After that, when I try to start Apache2 the "The requested operation has failed!" error pop-up appears. If I comment the lines that I've inserted into httpd.conf, Apache works again. The lines are:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
(...)
LoadModule php5_module "c:/Program Files (x86)/php_5.4.9/php5.dll"
(...)
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/php_5.4.9"
```

I've spent a lot of hours and searched but couldn't find a similar problem to mine nor a solution of my own. Does anybody has a hint on this?

Thank you very much,
João

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the working AMP stacks for Windows like Zend Server CE, XAMPP, WAMP Server?

Comment: Forget the *AMP stacks, why do you want dompdf?  Go look up `wkhtmltopdf`, which doesn't require any of that crap.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. During my research, I came across this link, and was guiding through it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818093/how-to-print-html-to-pdf I'll take a look at wkhtmltopdf, thanks!